# how to delete columns with less than 20 repetitions on a hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to learn about deleting  user_id's repeated in less than 20 times in ratings table (id's with less than 20 votes mess up the prediction)

```
delete * FROM rating
WHERE COUNT(user_id) <20;
```

Below is the error I have gotten: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 3:6 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'COUNT'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two big problems

- Your query is wrong. to work properly you need to use aggregation function `count` with groupby on `user_id` columns.
- You can not delete records using `delete` statement unless you table is `transactional table.`

To delete the record from **non-transnational table** you need to use `insert overwrite` statement to overwrite the table with the records you want.

**Syntax:**

```
Insert overwrite table select * from <table_name> where <condition>
```

you code should look like this

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE rating 
SELECT * 
FROM   rating 
WHERE  
user_id IN 
       ( 
        SELECT   user_id 
        FROM     rating 
        GROUP BY(user_id) 
        HAVING   count(user_id) > 20 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having [transactional table](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/using-hive-acid-transactions-to-insert-update-and-delete-data/) then you can **`delete user_id`** having count less than **`20`** with the following statement.

```
hive> delete from rating where user_id in 
      (select user_id from rating group by user_id having count(user_id) < 20);
```